# MongoDB Bson Document depth

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB 3.4 Documentation its mentioned that

> MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents

But i was able to insert documents with more than 100 levels, so is my understanding of document nesting is wrong? what I am missing here could anyone please point out?
below are the two stored document:

> db.check.find()
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("598da4250de4a665225f2741"), "k1" : { "k2" : { "k3"
>   : { "k4" : { "k5" : { "k6" : { "k7" : { "k8" : { "k9" : { "k10" : {
>   "k11" : { "k12" : { "k13" : { "k14" : { "k15" : { "k16" : { "k17" : {
>   "k18" : { "k19" : { "k20" : { " k21" : { "k22" : { "k23" : { "k24" : {
>   "k25" : { "k26" : { "k27" : { "k28" : { "k29" : { "k30" : { "k31" : {
>   "k32" : { " k33" : { "k34" : { "k35" : { "k36" : { "k37" : { "k38" : {
>   "k39" : { "k40" : { "k41" : { "k42" : { "k43" : { "k44" : { " k45" : {
>   "k46" : { "k47" : { "k48" : { "k49" : { "k50" : { "k51" : { "k52" : {
>   "k53" : { "k54" : { "k55" : { "k56" : { " k57" : { "k58" : { "k59" : {
>   "k60" : { "k61" : { "k62" : { "k63" : { "k64" : { "k65" : { "k66" : {
>   "k67" : { "k68" : { " k69" : { "k70" : { "k71" : { "k72" : { "k73" : {
>   "k74" : { "k75" : { "k76" : { "k77" : { "k78" : { "k79" : { "k80" : {
>   " k81" : { "k82" : { "k83" : { "k84" : { "k85" : { "k86" : { "k87" : {
>   "k88" : { "k89" : { "k90" : { "k91" : { "k92" : { " k93" : { "k94" : {
>   "k95" : { "k96" : { "k97" : { "k98" : { "k99" : { "k100" : { "k101" :
>   "hi" } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
>   } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
>   } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("598da502d662e277bf7971b0"), "k1" : { "k2" : { "k3"
>   : { "k4" : { "k5" : { "k6" : { "k7" : { "k8" : { "k9" : { "k10" : {
>   "k11" : { "k12" : { "k13" : { "k14" : { "k15" : { "k16" : { "k17" : {
>   "k18" : { "k19" : { "k20" : { " k21" : { "k22" : { "k23" : { "k24" : {
>   "k25" : { "k26" : { "k27" : { "k28" : { "k29" : { "k30" : { "k31" : {
>   "k32" : { " k33" : { "k34" : { "k35" : { "k36" : { "k37" : { "k38" : {
>   "k39" : { "k40" : { "k41" : { "k42" : { "k43" : { "k44" : { " k45" : {
>   "k46" : { "k47" : { "k48" : { "k49" : { "k50" : { "k51" : { "k52" : {
>   "k53" : { "k54" : { "k55" : { "k56" : { " k57" : { "k58" : { "k59" : {
>   "k60" : { "k61" : { "k62" : { "k63" : { "k64" : { "k65" : { "k66" : {
>   "k67" : { "k68" : { " k69" : { "k70" : { "k71" : { "k72" : { "k73" : {
>   "k74" : { "k75" : { "k76" : { "k77" : { "k78" : { "k79" : { "k80" : {
>   " k81" : { "k82" : { "k83" : { "k84" : { "k85" : { "k86" : { "k87" : {
>   "k88" : { "k89" : { "k90" : { "k91" : { "k92" : { " k93" : { "k94" : {
>   "k95" : { "k96" : { "k97" : { "k98" : { "k99" : { "k100" : { "k101" :
>   { "k102" : "hi2" } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
>   } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
>   } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
>   } } } } }
>   >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has some slack within the recommended nesting limit, the hard limit is actually 200 nested documents.

See here - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/bson/bson_depth.h#L39

For more information see this Jira item - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10578

Comment: Ok..thanks for the links..so recommend is 100 max allowable is 200!